# Sharer.js and angular 8 doesn't work - social sharing

Tags: angular, window

I am working on an angular 8 project and i had to implement the social sharing. I am trying to use `sharer.js` (https://ellisonleao.github.io/sharer.js/) but it seems that something is not going well.

I had imported sharer through CDN and placed in the index.html.

In the component, on the `ngAfterInit()` i had tried this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      ;(window as any).Sharer.init()
   })
}
```

and also

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        ;(window as any).Sharer.init()
      })
    })
  }
```

and the html is:

```
<span data-sharer="twitter" data-title="testingggg" data-url="https://ellisonleao.github.io/sharer.js/">TEST</span>
```

After clicking on the HTML element nothing happens. Any suggestion?

Reading the documentation it seems that you only need to initialize the module but it doesn't work.
the same thing was done in an angular 9 project and it works. the steps are the same

Answer (score 0):

This approach works in Angular 9 and I would expect it to also work in Angular 8.

1.Install sharer

```
npm install sharer.js
```

2.Add to /angular.json

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/sharer.js/sharer.min.js"
]
```

3.Add sharer to your .ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

 // Declare external javascript library symbol.
declare var Sharer: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'sharer',
    templateUrl: './sharer.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./sharer.component.scss'],
})
export class SharerComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit() {
        // Initialize sharer javascript library.
        Sharer.init();
    }
}
```

4.Add sharer to your .html e.g.

```
<button class="button" data-sharer="twitter" data-title="Checkout Sharer.js!" data-hashtags="awesome, sharer.js" data-url="https://ellisonleao.github.io/sharer.js/">Share on Twitter</button>
```